# Why is @ not matching for query_string query in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've a field with email ids, when I try to match the whole email id, it doesn't match the document, but when I don't include @ the document matches. I tried replacing @ with . and *, none of them helped in matching.

How do I match whole email?

Eg doc:

```
{
  ...
  "email": "sample@gmail.com"
}
```

Eg failure query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "email",
      "query": "*mple@gmail.c*"
    }
  }
}
```

Eg success query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "email",
      "query": "*ample*"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: whats the used analyzer on this field? maybe your analyzer cuts out the @ symbol

Comment: I'm not specifying any analyzer during query, I don't see any analyzer in _mapping, so must be default analyzer, is there an analyzer that will work for this case?

Comment: well on one hand you could first check with termvec https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html if the analyzer really cutted that symbol out, but I guess so. maybe you need for this field then smthing like https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by Richie in another post, here it wasn't matching your search query as, default analyzer in Elastic is `standard` analyzer, which removes the special character from the text, during tokenization process.

You need to do below things in order to make it work.

1. Define custom analyzer which uses the [UAX URL tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html.)
2. Use your custom analyzer on the fields where you want `@` to be searchable. Define this in your ES schema.
3. Check the O/P of `http://localhost:9200/{your_index_name}/_mapping` where replace **your_index_name** with your index name and verify the fields now uses, custom analyzer.
4. **Re-index the whole the data, as changing analyzer of a field is a breaking changes and only after you re-index the whole data, with new mapping then it will have expected tokens.**
5. Check the tokens generated for your fields, using [_analyze api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html). and now it should have tokens consisting `@`.

Let me know if you face any issue implementing this.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer, I'm having trouble finding resources for creating custom analyzer in index and applying that to a specific field using elasticsearch Java API, please point me to it. That will fully solve the issue for me.

Comment: @ChakradarRaju , as I mentioned, you need to update the mapping of your index, and specify the custom analyzer in your mapping? Are u defining a mapping for your index or using the dynamic mapping ?

Comment: I'm defining mapping that we do when we create the index, like this using ES's Java API:
new CreateIndexRequest(ESClient.callIndex)
                .mapping(callDocType, turnsField, "type=nested", timeField, "type=date", categoriesList, "type=nested").

Mapping is created for other fields dynamically.

Comment: @ChakradarRaju , did you delete the old index and created a new index with updated mapping ?

Comment: I still didn't find how to set custom analyzer for a specific field using ES Java API. So I'm just using regular match query, which tokenize both query and data the same way, so it might look like it is working, but it is not working perfect. ie, if the document has abc@pqr.com and def@xyz.com, searching for abc@xyz.com will match.

Comment: its very easy to define.. can you provide access to ur code, so that I can check it throughly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, so from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html you can see that Standard analyzer makes

```
POST _analyze
{
  "text": "Email me at john.smith@global-international.com"
}
```

to

```
[ Email, me, at, john.smith, global, international.com ]
```

That uax_url_email analyzer makes

```
 [ Email, me, at, john.smith@global-international.com ]
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand what is going wrong.
I have created a custom analyzer in the index, but I'm having trouble applying that analyzer to an existing field, is it possible to do it?

Comment: you need to reindex when you change the analyzer

Comment: with https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html that is simple. pls accept answer when you have done it :)

Comment: I still didn't find how to set custom analyzer for a specific field using ES Java API. So I'm just using regular match query, which tokenize both query and data the same way, so it might look like it is working, but it is not working perfect. ie, if the document has abc@pqr.com and def@xyz.com, searching for abc@xyz.com will match.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html Setting custom mapping is not so hard. Maybe just get the current Mapping from your index with a  GET request, then you modify this piece of json with replacing standard analyzer with uax_url_email for your email containing field, then you create a new index, upload this modified json with PUT and then use the reindex api to reindex from old to new index with new mapping.

Comment: "attendees" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          }, this is how the field is in GET <index>/_mapping, i don't see analyzer field in it

Comment: then modify this to "attendees" : { "type" : "text", "analyzer": "uax_url_email" "fields" : { "keyword" : { "type" : "keyword", "ignore_above" : 256 } }